# Postgres & JPA named queries - any (*) value in WHERE

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, orm, named-query

I want to write filter queries for some specific GET cases.

What I am doing right now is writing separate queries for each case, which is pretty time-consuming. Instead, I would like to write one big named query, where I can either put a value into the WHERE clause if a filter is set, otherwise ANY. Is this possible with JPA?
This is an example controller which returns payments by a specific client-ID:

```
public List<PaymentEntity> findAllByClientId(final int page, final int pageSize, final String fromDate,
        final String toDate, final Long clientId) {
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("clientId", clientId);
    return super.findWithNamedQueryPagination("PaymentEntity.findAllWithPaginationByClientId", parameters,
            PaymentEntity.class, page, pageSize, fromDate, toDate);
}
```

And this is the belonging named query:

```
SELECT i FROM PaymentEntity i WHERE i.clientContractData.client.id = :clientId AND i.createdAt BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate ORDER BY i.createdAt DESC
```

What I would like to now is to be able to pass a parameter like this:

```
    if(clientId == null) {
        parameters.put("clientId", "*");
    } else {
        parameters.put("clientId", clientId);
    }
```

But now of course I get an type error: `Parameter value [*] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]`

What would be the best way to accomplish this? Do I have to write native queries or is there a way with named queries?

**Edit to clarify:** The example above shows a query with type `Long`, but I need to do this with `String` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to alter your query like:

```
WHERE (i.clientContractData.client.id = :clientId or :clientId = -1)
```

Note: I think that references in JPA goes as far as 2 levels deep and here you have 3 levels:

```
i.clientContractData.client.id
```

you may need to use an extra explicit join here

Comment: did you mean `:clientId is null` ?

Comment: I guess its up to OP to decide what to use as ANY value

Comment: I edited the question. This is a good solution for type Long but unfortunately I need a solution that works for Strings as well. For the Levels - It is working with 3 Levels :) I wrote some tests for that case.

Comment: It seems that the 3-Level-Deep reference is indeed a problem in a WHERE clause in combination with an OR statement. When I store the client inside the payment and do it like this it works: `SELECT i FROM PaymentEntity i WHERE (:clientId IS NULL OR i.client.id = :clientId) AND i.createdAt BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate ORDER BY i.createdAt DESC`

Answer (score 0):

Updated query ,

```
SELECT i FROM PaymentEntity i WHERE 
       ((i.clientContractData.client.id = :clientId and :clientId IS NOT NULL) 
        or (i.clientContractData.client.id IS NOT NULL AND :clientId IS NULL)) 
         AND i.createdAt BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate ORDER BY i.createdAt DESC
```

Send null value if clientId is null:

```
if(clientId == null) {
    parameters.put("clientId", null);
} else {
    parameters.put("clientId", clientId);
}
```

You use rsql-jpa-specification project for more complicated cases:

https://github.com/perplexhub/rsql-jpa-specification

Comment: This looks like a good solution for long & string, I will try this today and get back to you! Although the queries will get pretty long when I have a lot of values to filter :)

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me only results where a `PaymentEntity` also has a related `clientContractData`, but by default I need all entries. Actually I do not understand why this is not working: `SELECT i FROM PaymentEntity i WHERE (:clientId IS NULL OR i.clientContractData.client.id = :clientId) AND i.createdAt BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate ORDER BY i.createdAt DESC`. This returns only payments with clientcontractdata as well. Maybe this is due to the 3-Level-Deep nesting mentioned by @Maciej Kowalski?